# QR Scanner RunTimeError

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter program which will be used to scan QR codes and that QR code will then return a JSON.

the package I am using is
**flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0**

```
class homePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const homePage({super.key});

  Future scanQRCode(BuildContext context) async {
    var res = "";
    res = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
        '#ff6666', "Stop", true, ScanMode.QR);
    var info = jsonDecode(res);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Details(
            regNo: info["regNo"].toString(),
            event: info["slug"].toString(),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var vertical = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          scanQRCode(context);
        },
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent[700]),
        child: Text(
          "Scan",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: vertical * 0.03),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The QR scanner in itself works just fine but the issue which i am facing is whenever i stop the scanner without actually scanning a QR code or just pressing the phone back button, it throws a run time error:

***Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: -1
Tried calling:***